# the_time() isn't working properly, need help for newbie

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I wanted wrapping month, day, and year separately inside divs and 
I tried doing this

```
function posted_on_main_page() {
    $format= '<div class="posted-date">
                  <div class="posted-month">%1$s</div>
                  <div class="posted-day">%2$s</div>
                  <div class="posted-year">%3$s</div>
              </div>';
    $month = the_time('M');
    $date = the_time('j');
    $year = the_time('Y');
    printf($format, $month, $date, $year);

}
```

but for some reasons when I inspect element it displays date before everything

```
Jun272012<div class="posted-date">
              <div class="posted-month"></div>
              <div class="posted-day"></div>
              <div class="posted-year"></div>
         </div>
```

If you have another solution to wrap date separately pls help me out.

 Thnx in advance!

Comment: You are using `printf`wrong. Please have a look at [its documentation](http://php.net/printf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than calling **the_time($format)**, use **[get_the_time($format)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time)**. This returns the value, rather than echoing it immediately.